# How can I keep the Menu control from generating extra classes and styles in the UL and LI tags?

Tags: asp.net

So I am working on an assignment for school where our ASP project needs to have a menu control that is linked to a site map.  If it wasn't for the site map, I would just hand code the ul and li tags into the menus that I usually use on my sites.  But since it needs to be linked to the site map, I have to use the Menu control.  My issue with this control(and a lot of other controls give me this issue) is that it generates a lot of extra css classes and inline styles.  How can I set the Menu control to generate ONLY the ul and li tags? like below:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#>Top-Level Link</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Submenu Link</a></li>
      </ul></li>
   <li><a href="#">No Submenu</a></li>
</ul>
```

And NOT like below:

```
<ul class="level1 static" tabindex="0" role="menubar" style="position: relative; width: auto; float: left;">
        <li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:2" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="Manage student grades." class="popout level1 static" tabindex="-1">Grades</a><ul class="level2 dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:2" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
            <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a title="View the grades of every student." class="level2 dynamic" href="/ViewGrades.aspx" tabindex="-1">
View Grades
                </a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a title="Add a grade for a specific student." class="level2 dynamic" href="/AddGrade.aspx" tabindex="-1">
Add Grades
                </a></li>
        </ul></li><li class="has-popup static" aria-haspopup="Menu1:submenu:6" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;"><a title="Maintain different stuff." class="popout level1 static" tabindex="-1">Maintenance</a><ul class="level2 dynamic" id="Menu1:submenu:6" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px;">
            <li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a title="Manage the students." class="level2 dynamic" href="/Students.aspx" tabindex="-1">
Students
                </a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a title="Manage the courses." class="level2 dynamic" href="/Courses.aspx" tabindex="-1">
Courses
                </a></li><li role="menuitem" class="dynamic" style="position: relative;"><a title="Manage the semesters." class="level2 dynamic" href="/Semesters.aspx" tabindex="-1">
Semesters
                </a></li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>
```

If my Menu control is this:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false"/>
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try this `<asp:Menu IncludeStyleBlock="False" ...` if it can help you

Comment: That just got rid of the arrows that tell you if there's a submenu.

Comment: Hmm, are you using javascript or jquery? Then there can be a work around

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom rendering based on your sitemap content. You don't need to use sitemap datasource or the menu control. (I'm using this for asp.net mvc projects, but should work with webforms)

The example renders the 1st level nodes, you can implement recursion etc. for your needs. (You need to convert the razor code to aspx syntax.)

```
<ul>
    @foreach( SiteMapNode node in SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes )
    {
        <li><a href="@node.Url">@node.Title</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```